# I cannot echo the field in plugin ACF for wordpress

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I cannot echo the field plugin ACF for wordpress.
Though i try to print out the field that is saved in database as for example 'social_icon_1'. It is not printing out. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    if(get_locale() == 'uk') {
        echo get_field('social_icon_1');
?>

<p>
    <?php the_field('social_icon_1'); ?>
</p>

<?php
    }
```

And here is the screenshot of the created field:

[image]

Live example of the sites is:
 [slotsviewer.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go7W3.png),
[http://онлайн-казино-украины.com.ua/](http://xn-----6kcbb4bhccledzdfebl4b8cxk.com.ua)

Regards,
Maksym